# Kotlin 1.3.6X plugin cannot be installed (settings say unverified)

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, intellij-plugin

Build: AI-192.6817.14.36.5994180, 201911071727,

AI-192.6817.14.36.5994180, JRE 1.8.0_212-release-1586-b04x64 JetBrains s.r.o, OS Windows 10(amd64) v10.0 , screens 1920x1080, 1920x1080

AS: 3.6 Beta 4; Kotlin plugin: 1.3.50-release-Studio3.6-1; Android Gradle Plugin: 3.6.0-beta04; Gradle: 6.0.1; NDK: from local.properties: (not specified), latest from SDK: (not found); LLDB: pinned revision 3.1 not found, latest from SDK: (package not found); CMake: from local.properties: (not specified), latest from SDK: (not found), from PATH: (not found)

Check attached image. It appears Kotlin 1.3.6X is not installable from Android Studio.

Comment: I have posted this question because it was P1 issue  and it can help to many of us https://issuetracker.google.com/u/1/issues/145468273

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With Reference to [google issue tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/u/1/issues/145468273) this has been fixed in latest version.

you can re-open or open new issue with reference to this https://issuetracker.google.com/u/1/issues/145468273 if you face the same.

Response from google

> This happens after JetBrains releases a new Kotlin plugin version and
> before Android Studio verifies it, usually a short time window. Should
> not happen now since Android Studio has verified all existing Kotlin
> stable versions.